# Solving the same problem in different ways obtaining different answers

Tags: combinatorics, recursion, inclusion-exclusion

I am trying to solve this question in different ways, but results don't tally, and some of them look incorrect to me. Can someone point out where are the loopholes in these logics?

> Count the number of $n$-binary strings with at least $(n − 3)$ consecutive $1$s

**1. Using inclusion-exclusion:**

To obtain the number of binary strings of length $n$ and $(n − 3)$ consecutive $1$s, count number of ways $1$ can be placed in $(n-3)$ consecutive places, subtract number of ways $1$ can be placed in $(n-2)$ consecutive places (because those are counted twice for $(n-3)$), add number of ways $1$ can be placed in $(n-1)$ consecutive places (because those are subtracted twice for $(n-2)$), subtract number of ways $1$ can be placed in $n$ consecutive places (because those are counted twice for $(n-1)$).

Counting for $(n-3)$ case above. These $(n-3)$ $1$s can be placed among the remaining 3 digits in 4 ways. (left most position, right most position, left to the middle digit, right to the middle digit), and those 3 digits can be written in $2^3$ ways (each can be either 0 or 1). So the count for $(n-3)$ consecutive $1$s = $4.2^3=32$.

Similarly, count for $(n-2)$ is $3.2^2=12$.

count for $(n-1)$ is $2.2=4$.

count for $n$ is $1$.

So required count = $32 -12+4-1=23$.

**2. Using recurrence:**

Let $a_n$ be the count of ways an $n$-binary string can be made without $(n-3)$ consecutive $1$s. Then our required count will be $2^n - a_n$.

Now, consider the set of these $a_n$ arrangements. If we place a binary bit after them, then total number of possible binaries will be $2 a_n$ (as the last bit is either a $0$ or a $1$). The invalid cases will be only those cases where the last $(n-4)$ digits were all $1$ in the n-binary, and an $1$ is placed at the end, resulting in $(n-3)$ consecutive $1$s. Number of such cases = $2^3$ (because the 4th bit should be 0, and 5th to nth bit all 1s.)

So we get the recurrence relation, $2a_n=a_{n+1}+2^3$.

Solving this ..

$2a_{n-1}-a_{n}=2^3$

$2^2a_{n-2}-2a_{n-1}=2^4$

...

$2^{n-4}a_{4}-2^{n-5}a_{5}=2^{n-2}$

Adding all, we get, $2^{n-4}a_{4}-a_{n}=8(2^{n-4}-1)$

Base case $a_4=1$ (all 0s to place in one way).

So, $a_n=2^{n-4}-8(2^{n-4}-1)$

Required count = $2^n - 2^{n-4}+8(2^{n-4}-1)=2^n+2^{n-1}-2^{n-4}-2^3=3.2^{n-1}-2^{n-4}-2^3=23.2^{n-4}-8.$

**3. Using generating function:**

Coefficient of x less than n+1 and more than (n-3) in $(1+x+x^{n-3})^4$

Now, checking results for n=5, by manually counting all possible binaries, I am getting 19.

But inclusion-exclusion formula above gives 32, the recurrence formula gives 38, the generating function gives 55. All are mismatch. Please suggest where am I wrong in calculating these.

Comment: For example, your generating function overcounts it with $x\cdot x^{n-3}\cdot 1\cdot 1$ and $x^{n-3}\cdot x\cdot 1\cdot 1$ both referring to the same string with $n-2$ ones followed by 2 zeros.

Comment: With your inclusion-exclusion, that would be the correct answer for large enough $n$, but for $n\leq 5$ you can fit at least two strings of nonadjacent consecutive $(n-3)$ 1s into the same string $11011$ for $n=5$, $1010$ etc for $n=4$ and the empty string fits into everywhere for $n=3$.  They got counted multiple times which is why you end up with $>2^n$ for $n=3,4$.

Comment: With your recurrence, $2a_4=a_5+8$ is clearly wrong when $a_4=1$.  The only string for $a_4$ is $0000$, and when you go from $a_4$ to $a_5$ you count $00001$, $00000$ and subtract from it $xxx11$.  The root of this trouble is $n$ is doing two different jobs in your $a_n$: you want to keep $n-3$ (ones) fixed in but allow $n$ to increase by $1$ to get to a longer string.

Comment: Hmm.. something else is wrong with your inclusion-exclusion.  For $n\geq 6$ the correct answer is 20, as the middle $n-6$ are forced to be ones and any 3 consecutive ones in the remaining. You counted exactly $n-1$ consecutive ones with $3-2+1=2$ times each, as is the string of all 1s for $4-3+2-1=2$ times.  These overcounting comes from pairwise intersections of where the $n-3$ overlaps smaller than $n-4$.

Comment: Thanks user10354138 for your answers, it really helped me clarify my thinking for inclusion-exclusion. There might be some way to do it using recurrence as well. I am thinking. In case I can find out any answer, will post in the answer.